# What's the polynomial involved in the PCP theorem?

Tags: proof-techniques, probabilistic-algorithms

Statements of the [PCP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCP_theorem) always speak of a proof of length $poly(n)$. But what polynomial is that exactly? Could you actually construct the PCP for some mathematical fact in real life?

Comment: Each problem has it's own polynomial, and there exist problems with arbitrary large polynomials, otherwise it wouldn't be denoted so.

Comment: For 3SAT the polynomial is $n^{1+o(1)}$, see for example [Moshkovitz–Raz](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/eccc-reports/2008/TR08-071/index.html) and the references therein.

Comment: This is more related to the definition of NP than to PCP. One of the defined requirements for a problem to be in NP is that for each yes-answer there exists a certificate of polynomial size, that is at most $O(n^c)$ for some constant c you might choose.